# Is there a Groovier way to substring?

Tags: java, http, groovy

I'm using more groovy these days and I ran into an issue where I wanted to take the substring up to a known character. In short, I'm trying to grab a session cookie from an HTTP header. My code is uglified like so:

```
def cookie = connection.headerFields.find{ it.key =='Set-Cookie'}.value[0]
cookie = cookie[0..cookie.indexOf(';')-1]
```

Where connection is a reference to a URLConnection. Without the extra manipulation I get a value like `"[JSESSIONID=72Q4TCEEDC21GX9152E7702A23DC3854E; Path=/; Secure]"`. The end result is the expected session id `"JSESSIONID=72Q4TCEEDC21GX9152E7702A23DC3854E"`. But I can't help thinking there must be a groovier way to go about this. In short, I'm missing a `substringToString(';')` that I think I may have seen in at least one other language. Overall, I think there's probably 4-5 better ways to grab the cookie without the other Path and secure verbiage.

Comment: Not sure if there's a nicer-looking way, but you won't gain any efficiency from using a different method.  Also, since it's only the second line you're looking to improve, I don't think you have all that much to gain in terms of readability either. (I would not be surprised to hear that there's a nicer way to do the entire job of grabbing a cookie, however.)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're complicating the things. Why can't you do like this:

```
//  if you want all cookies
def cookies = request.cookies  

// if you need a particular cookie
def cookie = request.cookies.find { it == 'cookie-name' }
```

The way above works for controllers. From service layer you need to do first smth like this:

```
def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request
```

though I wouldn't recommend to do so.

Comment: Sounds good but I'm not sure which package you're pulling things from. Where is RequestContextHolder? What is the service layer? And why are you giving an answer you wouldn't recommend? I'm confused. I'm used to vanilla Java 1.6 so I don't follow what you say on controllers and service layers.

Comment: If you access the 'request' object from a controller you don't have to import any packages: `request` & `response` are special data members, which are injected into your controller instances by grails. These objects are instances of Java `HttpServletRequest` & `HttpServletResponse` respectively.

Also you can access request from service layer. Just import `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder` and set up a `request` variable as I showed below.
But this way is not recommended: services is a data layer, which should not have anything to do with any particular request.

Comment: For more info about grails controllers & services look:
http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html

&

http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#services

Comment: I think I understand. As I said above, I'm using vanilla Java/Groovy. I'm not using any frameworks, servlets or service layers. This is an ad-hoc groovy script run from an Ant build that scrapes and publishes to a wiki page. I don't have a spring framework.web.context or anything. Just a plain URL object instance with some streams is all I have going.